# How to Assign Dynamic Values to Custom Parameters in D2L Basic LTI

Tags: desire2learn, lti

Within "Manage External Learning Tools" D2L provides the ability to define custom LTI parameters. I created such a parameter, and I now want to assign a dynamic value to the customer parameter via JavaScript prior to posting the request to the 3rd party provider.

For example, the user_id LTI parameter is assigned the D2L-only user ID value which does not align with the campus-wide authentication. However, it is possible to get the campus-wide user ID via JavaScript, and I would like to assign this to a custom LTI parameter like custom_campus_user_id.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to External Learning Tools at the org, and go into Settings (v10) or Configure Tool Consumer Information (v9.2 – v9.4.1), there are three checkboxes for allowing the D2L defined user fields to be passed in an LTI link as custom parameters. It appears it is system username that contains the value you are looking for.

[image: LTI Config Page]

Comment: This doesnt answer his question.By checking the 'send user details' checkboxes, D2L user details are sent over with LTI request. The question mentions about some other user identifier.